# First steps to detailed report in power BI

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have some experience in SSRS, but new in Power BI.
Would you prompt me please the first step create a detailed report in Power BI.

Initial dataset:

```
Client Country Month
John   USA     jan
Ivan   Russia  feb
Albert England mar
...    ...     ...
```

Desirable result:
The matrix with aggregations on the top of the Page:

```
Clients    jan  feb mar
England    50   5   30
USA        75   7   15
Russia     25   5   15
```

By clicking on the numbers, I want to get filtered information about clients on the bottom of the Page (e.g. if we click on 50, we get 50 rows with clients from England in January):

```
Client Country Month
Mary   England jan
Mick   England jan
Albert England jan
...    ...     ...
```

Comment: Power BI doesnot has such a high level function similar to SAP, it is beyond the limit already.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating 2 linked objects in Power BI: the matrix and the table.

Matrix:

```
Rows = Country
Columns = Month 
Values = Count of ClientS
```

Table:

```
Values = Country, Month, Clients
```